# Unwanted White Space

Tags: html, css

I wanted to add 3 horizontal paragraphs next to eachother.
The only way I could figure it out is by using the position property but I got this as a result.

http://postimg.org/image/ti454xgz7/

I'm trying to make it as clean as possible but it always appears this way and this is my code:

```
  <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Promotions </title>
<link href="project.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body class="body">
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="tyre plus.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="promotions.html">Promotions</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Customers</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Order Now</a></li>
    <li><a href="branches.html">Branches</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">References</a></li>

</ul>

  <header><img class="banner" src="images/banner.jpg" width="1000" height="120" alt=" Tyre Plus Banner"/></header>
  <br>
  <br>
  <nav></nav>
  <br><br> <br><br><br>
  <section>
<img class="img2" src="C:\Users\Ghanim\Downloads\tyre plus\tyre plus\loyalty.jpg" alt="Loyalty Cards" ></img>
<br><br><br> <br><br><br>
<h2> 15% Blue Loyalty Card </h2>
<p> 15% off on following services: 
<ul>
<li> Disk Skimming </li>
<li> Tyre Balancing </li>
<li> Tyre Fitting </li>
<li> Oil Change </li>
<li> Alignment </li>

<li class="li"> <b><em> FREE Rotation </b></em> </li> 
<li class="li"> <b><em> FREE 50 Checkpoint Check-Up </b></em> </li> 
</ul>
</p>

<h2 class="center" align="center"> 20% Silver Loyalty Card </h2>
<p class="center"align="center"> 20% off on following services: </p>
<p class="center"align="center"> Disk Skimming </p>
<p class="center"align="center"> Tyre Balancing </p>
<p class="center"align="center"> Tyre Fitting </p>
<p class="center"align="center"> Oil Change </p>
<p class="center"align="center"> Alignment </p>
<p class="center"align="center" > <b><em> <span style="color:red"> FREE Rotation </span> </b></em> <p>
<p class="center" align="center"> <b><em> <span style="color:red"> FREE 50 Checkpoint Check-Up </span> </b></em> <p>


<h2 class="right" align="right"> 30% Gold Loyalty Card </h2>
<p class="right" align="right"> 30% off on following services: </p>
<p class="right"align="right"> Disk Skimming </p>
<p class="right"align="right"> Tyre Balancing </p>
<p class="right"align="right"> Tyre Fitting </p>
<p class="right"align="right"> Oil Change </p>
<p class="right"align="right"> Alignment </p>
<p class="right"align="right" > <b><em> <span style="color:red"> FREE Rotation </span> </b></em> <p>
<p class="right" align="right"> <b><em> <span style="color:red"> FREE 50 Checkpoint Check-Up </span> </b></em> <p>
<p class="right"align="right" > <b><em> <span style="color:red"> FREE Alignment Check-Up </span> </b></em> <p>
<p class="right"align="right" > <b><em> <span style="color:red"> FREE Oil To-Up </span> </b></em> <p>

  </section>

  <hr>
  <footer class="footer">Copyright &copy 2015 All Rights Reserved - Tyre Plus - Central Trading Company </footer>
  <p class="footer2"> For more info please contact us on <a href="mailto:tyreplus.ae"> Tyre Plus </a>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.banner
{
position:relative;
text-align: center;
right:-100px;
margin-top:50px;
}

.body
{
background-color: #A9E2F3;
border: 40px solid;
border-color: #0B173B;
padding: 30px;

}


.para
{
margin:auto;
text-align: center;
width:800px;
font-family: calibri;
font-size: 18px;
margin-bottom:30px;
font-style: oblique;
}

.para2
{
font-family: calibri;
right:-50px;
position:relative;
font-size: 14px;

}

.para3
{
font-family: calibri;
right:-90px;
position:relative;
}

.alshami
{
position:relative;
right: -550px;
top:-500px;
}

.h1
{
font-size: 34px;
color:black;
font-family:arial;
text-align: center;

}

.img
{
display:block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

.img2
{
display:block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

.footer
{
margin-top:30px;
position:relative;
right:-310px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
font-size: 18px;
font-family: arial;
}

.footer2
{
position:relative;
right:-400px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
font-size: 18px;
font-family: arial;
}

#menu {
    list-style:none;
    width:910px;
    margin:30px auto 0px auto;
    height:43px;
    padding:0px 20px 0px 20px;

    /* Rounded Corners */

    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;

    /* Background color and gradients */

    background: #014464;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0272a7, #013953);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#0272a7), to(#013953));

    /* Borders */

    border: 1px solid #002232;

    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 1px #edf9ff;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 1px #edf9ff;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 1px #edf9ff;
}

#menu li {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px;
    margin-right:30px;
    margin-top:7px;
    border:none;
}

#menu li:hover {
    border: 1px solid #777777;
    padding: 4px 9px 4px 9px;

    /* Background color and gradients */

    background: #F4F4F4;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F4F4F4, #EEEEEE);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#F4F4F4), to(#EEEEEE));

    /* Rounded corners */

    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
}

#menu li a {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px; 
    color: #EEEEEE;
    display:block;
    outline:0;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
}

#menu li:hover a {
    color:#161616;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #FFFFFF;
}
#menu li .drop {
    padding-right:21px;
    background:url("img/drop.png") no-repeat right 8px;
}
#menu li:hover .drop {
    background:url("img/drop.png") no-repeat right 7px;
}

.loyalty
{
position:relative;
right:-500px;
top:-230px;
}

.li
{

font-style: italic;
color: red;
}

.loyalty2
{
font-size:27px;
position:relative;
right:-500px;
top:-250px;
}

.center
{
position:relative;
top:-230px;
}

.right
{
position:relative;
top:-550px;
}
```

As well as the images here, my problem is aligning I don't know how to do it properly, horizontal alignment.

http://postimg.org/image/jqjr7bv3n/

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is an old technique, but you could use tables to help you format your site and paragraphs. If done correctly it can look very nice.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Comment: Oh wow that's very useful,

What about if I wanna do the same thing with images, it's possible too?

Comment: You should be able to plop anything into the table's columns or rows.

Comment: No problem. Let me know if you have any other questions. And if this answers your question please mark it accordingly. Good luck with your site! :D

Comment: @Ghanim The internet and web developers all over the world beg you NOT to use tables for your page layout! I don't want to downvote this answer - but you should reconsider it as it is bad advice.

Comment: I think tables can be used for quick formating and yes even the layout. However, chose what you will. That was my advice(I don't think its bad advice what so ever) and if you decide it is not for you then thats fine. There are always other methods you can use. You can use containers and then line everything up accordingly with css. I was just giving you the way I thought would be better.